# Save Evaluated Result To A Variable - nightmare web scraping

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, screen-scraping, nightmare

Here is the base code... there is require statements i skipped...
this code prints out a link in the console. i want to store that link in a variable to use it later.

```
app.post('/search', function(req, res){
    const val = req.body.searchText;
    
    const nightmare = new Nightmare({ 
        show: true 
    });

    let aa;
    
    (async function() {
        await nightmare
    
        .goto('https://google.com/')
        .insert('#tsf > div:nth-child(2) > div.A8SBwf > div.RNNXgb > div > div.a4bIc > input', val + ' + MuzzMusic.com')
        .click('#tsf > div:nth-child(2) > div.A8SBwf > div.FPdoLc.tfB0Bf > center > input.gNO89b')
        .click('#rso > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.r > a > h3')


        .evaluate(() => {
            aa = document.querySelector('#post-54106 > div > div.entry-content > p:nth-child(4) > a').href
            return aa
        })

        .end()
        .then(console.log)
    
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
        console.log('aa ==== ' + aa) //checking if it works
    
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
app.post('/search', async function(req, res){
    const val = req.body.searchText;
    
    const nightmare = new Nightmare({ 
        show: true 
    });

    let aa

    try {
        aa = await nightmare
            .goto('https://google.com/')
            .insert('#tsf > div:nth-child(2) > div.A8SBwf > div.RNNXgb > div > div.a4bIc > input', val + ' + MuzzMusic.com')
            .click('#tsf > div:nth-child(2) > div.A8SBwf > div.FPdoLc.tfB0Bf > center > input.gNO89b')
            .click('#rso > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.r > a > h3')
            .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#post-54106 > div > div.entry-content > p:nth-child(4) > a').href)
            .end()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    
    console.log('aa ==== ' + aa) //checking if it works
})
```

Comment: tried it your way...the variable's value is undefined

Comment: The question is not clear. Its undefined until it reachs the evaluate statement. The solution depends on your needs. Its static during the entire execution of the program? Then get it before starting the server.

Comment: the above code isn't complete. there are require and init elements i did not include in the above code, but it works. what i want to do is capture the link that is evaluated there. it prints when .then(console.log) is executed. i wanted to store the output(the link) into a variable so i can use it later. is it clear now?